# How to convert infix to prefix if the operator present in front of expression?

Tags: python, sympy

if an equation is (- 3 + 5), how could I convert it into prefix?
It's operator is in front of the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print the *unevaluate* expression with `srepr` it will show exactly how the expression is represented in SymPy/Python:

```
>>> from sympy import srepr, Add
>>> srepr(Add(-3,5,evaluate=False))
'Add(Integer(-3), Integer(5))'
```

I'm guessing you don't want this. The most general way of handling printing is to create a custom printer (and you would have to check the documentation on that). Alternatively, depending on how complicated of a case you want to deal with, you could handle a simple case like this:

```
>>> from sympy import Add, Mul, S, Symbol
>>> ops = {Add: '+(%s, %s)', Mul: '*(%s, %s)'}
>>> def pr(eq):
...    eq = S(eq)
...    if eq.func not in ops: return str(eq)
...    a, b = eq.as_two_terms()
...    return ops[eq.func] % (pr(a), pr(b))
>>> pr(x + y)
'+(x, y)'
>>> pr(3*x + y - z)
'+(y, +(*(-1, z), *(3, x)))'
```

There's an alternative to working with literal numbers so they will behave like symbols: create symbols with names being the strings of the numbers, e.g.

```
>>> a, b = (-3, 5)
>>> pr(a + b)  # -3 + 5 collapses automatically to 2
'2'
>>> a, b = [Symbol(str(i)) for i in (a,b)]  # create symbols from numbers
>>> pr(a + b)
'+(-3, 5)'
```